# How to read the user preference for save location (iCloud or local) for an iOS document-based app?

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocumentbrowservc

When developing a document based app, iOS automatically creates a preference about document storage (iCloud or local) in the Settings app: [image: The store location preference] How can I read this preference from my app? Please note that this is not the enable/disable iCloud switch for the app which is in the general iCloud section.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read that information from your app, it is used by the system to determine the default location when the user creates a new file within your app.

Comment: Do you have any Apple documentation on this setting? It popped up in the privacy settings of my app, which does not support iCloud at all. I have no idea what the setting does, and cannot find any Apple docs on it.